# data_mapper and json, json conflict with jsonj

Tags: json, ruby, ubuntu, datamapper

I Installed all gems to a new server. And after all got this error.

> /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2286:in
>   'raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate dm-serializer-1.2.2, because
>   json-2.0.3 conflicts with json (~> 1.6) (Gem::ConflictError)

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Gemfile.lock` file and again try `bundle install`. Still you got the same issue try to update your gem using `gem update` command.

Comment: bundle install - "Could not locate Gemfile". Did gem update. Cannot delete Gemfile.lock because I dont know where is it.

Comment: you can find `Gemfile.lock` on root directory.

Comment: there is not lock file at all